# Backbone.js: Splitting a model between views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, design-patterns

I found this great resource on patterns for splitting and subbing your Backbone views

http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#sub_views

However, there doesn't seem to be any existing patterns for how one should approach the model-add/view-create pattern in a way that accommodates a single model easily over multiple view cases.

Let's say, for instance, I have a User model, but I have two contexts for the Users on the page. For the purposes of illustration, let's say they're a Poster and a Commenter. The Poster's view (render and actions) are different from the Commenter's view.

Backbone says the best way to create new views is through the instantiation of a model, so outside of doing some sort of arbitrary property setting on the model (e.g. { poster : true } or { commenter : true }) and using that property and a case/switch to direct the model to instantiate the "right" view, what's a more agnostic and "Backboney" way of handling this problem?

Comment: "Backbone says the best way to create new views is through the instantiation of a model."  Where does it say this? I don't think a model should know anything about the views.

Comment: I can't seem to find the text I had read before, but it's certainly possible I misinterpreted it. That said, is there a better pattern for this? Maybe the collection handles the view routing?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you read. If you have a View that shows a collection, adding a new model to the collection will trigger an 'add' event, which the View is subscribed to. The handler in the view will create a new item view for that new model, adding it to its 'ul' or 'div' or whatever holds the item views... In this way, the creation/addition of the new model causes the view to respond by creating a new item view.  Still, all the collection knows is that there is a new model in it, and that it should tell anyone listening via its add event.

Comment: So does that mean that the collection *is* the proper place to handle that sort of directing? In practice, it seems to make sense, as your collections will be organized in the way your views would be...

Comment: If you are displaying a collection, then that is the way to do it. But, the model/collection itself does not create (or even know about) the views in that situation, either. Like [this](https://gist.github.com/1511225#file_live_tweets_view.js)... hard to find good examples...

Comment: [Here is the last part](http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-backbone-js-views/) of a really good article.  This part is about views... but really it might be better to start at the first part.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified sample from [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals).

```
var PhotoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "photos/:id": "route" },

  route: function(id) {
    var item = photoCollection.get(id);
    var view = new PhotoView({ model: item });
    var view2 = new PhotoView2({ model: item });

    something.html( view.render().el );
    somethingElse.html( view2.render().el );
  }
}):
```

Now, Backbone doesn't really have a preferred way to structure your app.  You could do this, creating and showing the views in the router.  Or, sometimes it is good to create your own AppController object, so you can leave the router to just routing.  Or, you could create a BaseView of some sort, which would create your sub-views...

But, the important thing is that both your views know nothing about each other.  And both will display and respond to the changes in the model in their own way. Also, the model knows nothing about the views displaying it.

[More info](http://aaronhardy.com/javascript/javascript-architecture-backbone-js-views/).

Another useful idea is the [event aggregator](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/).  Using this, your different components can communicate without tightly coupling themselves.

There are some [extensions for Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources), like (Backbone Marionette), which add some more structure.  You could look into those too.